# Permission error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm using windows 10, I'm using tesseract latest version for text recognition, below is the sample code I'm using now. But sometimes for some images, it gives the following.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract- 
OCR\tesseract.exe' 
config = ("-l eng --oem 1 --psm 7")
```

`text=pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Kesavan\Desktop\project\text Recogniton\opencv-text-recognition\images\cat.jpg'),config=config)`

print(text)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kesavan/PycharmProjects/Project/text recogniton/tester.py", line 6, in <module>
    text=pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Kesavan\Desktop\project\text Recogniton\opencv-text-recognition\images\cat.jpg'),config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Kesavan\PycharmProjects\learning\venv\Learnings\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 350, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "C:\Users\Kesavan\PycharmProjects\learning\venv\Learnings\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 349, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\Kesavan\PycharmProjects\learning\venv\Learnings\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 265, in run_and_get_output
    return output_file.read().decode('utf-8').strip()
  File "C:\Users\Kesavan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Kesavan\PycharmProjects\learning\venv\Learnings\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 177, in save
    cleanup(f.name)
  File "C:\Users\Kesavan\PycharmProjects\learning\venv\Learnings\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 134, in cleanup
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Kesavan\PycharmProjects\learning\venv\Learnings\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 131, in cleanup
    remove(filename)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\Kesavan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_jjp7wfoq.txt'
```

[This is the image for which I'm facing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DfbJ.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why didn't you post with right format?It can make people who want to answer you question more convenient.

Comment: I tried bro but while posting its changing

Answer (score 0):

try to upgrade to the latest pytesseract version or follow this workaround:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tesseract-ocr/IyPpisQ1E4U/tl3IP3gqAwAJ